# Define module layout in application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to set up modules without my Zend Framework application and am wondering how to configure the module to use its own layout script.

I am hoping to define it within my application.ini file, but am not sure what to do...

I have tried:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules.layout.layout = "dietplan"
resources.modules.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

and this...

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
dietplan.resources.layout.layout = "dietplan"
dietplan.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

But am getting nowhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible by default, you need an Controller Plugin. Very good Tutorial :

[Zend Layout + Modules](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/415-Self-Contained-Reusable-Zend-Framework-Modules-With-Standardised-Configurators.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I was looking for a simple solution and I think I just found something that will work for me. I will post it as an answer in a second.

Comment: Nevermind... I just realised that my default module had the new layout... argh.